Powershell: recursive file copying bug
I am deploying an angular application, and to copy dist files we use powershell script, which gives errors in ci pipeline (Azure DevOps, Linux build agent). This works fine locally on my windows machine.
The ci console output:

pwsh -NoProfile -File ./scripts/copy.ps1 -source ./build/en/* -destination ./build


copy.ps1: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument './build/en/GVS_Icons.eot'.

copy.ps1 looks like this
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$source,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$destination
)

Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Force -Recurse

Why is it failing?


Your symptom suggests that your pwsh call is made either from a POSIX-compatible shell such as bash or from PowerShell (on Unix).
In both cases, an argument such as ./build/en/* is subject to filename expansion (globbing) meaning that the shell itself expands the wildcard pattern to matching literal file paths up front, which are then passed as individual arguments to the target utility.[1]
To avoid this, problem, quote the argument:
# Note the use of '...' to prevent up-front filename expansion (globbing) on Unix.
pwsh -NoProfile -File ./scripts/copy.ps1 -source './build/en/*' -destination ./build


[1] Note that PowerShell does this only on Unix-like platforms and only when calling external programs, so as to emulate the behavior of POSIX-compatible shells in this respect.
